# How to add inline styles in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react. I've tried `{{style=color: "red"}}` but this gives me an error. Appreciate if you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to add inline styles in react. `style={{color: "red"}}` this is how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html):

```
// Result style: '10px'
<div style={{ height: 10 }}>
  Hello World!
</div>

// Result style: '10%'
<div style={{ height: '10%' }}>
  Hello World!
</div>
```